# SignalR: WebSockets Error 400 on Azure Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, websocket, signalr, virtual-machine, signalr-hub

I am hosting a WebSockets (SignalR) application on a Azure VM and I am experiencing the following 400 (Bad Request) error when connecting remotely.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxx.cloudapp.net/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&
clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=JMLk3b...&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22
dashboard%22%7D%5D&tid=10' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 
Unexpected response code: 400
```

This does not happen when accessing the app locally within the VM.

My suspicion is that this is a proxy problem as highlighted in [these](http://www.infoq.com/articles/Web-Sockets-Proxy-Servers) [various](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) [articles](https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/).

However, I can't seem to find any articles indicating whether one can actually host WebSockets apps on Azure VMs (I know they recently enabled [WS on Azure Websites](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/EnablingWebsocketsForSocketioNodeAppsOnMicrosoftAzure.aspx), but it seems as if the VMs don't have this feature yet).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being proxy servers (such as Squid) used client side at various ISPs and not proxy servers on the Azure side.

Comment: I have the same issue. Can you explain your solution a bit more please?

Comment: When establishing a network connection between your client (browser) and the server (SignalR host), there might be other networking devices/servers (such as proxy servers) involved in the process. These middlemen facilitates the comms between the client and server. Some of them, however, do not support the WebSockets protocol yet. So most likely, they consider the traffic coming through on port 80 to be plain old HTTP. The WS traffic coming through port 80 will then be rejected, resulting in a 400. The problem is most likely a proxy server at your ISP or hosting company.

Comment: Try to connect and send a message using this site: http://www.websocket.org/echo.html. If it fails, odds are that your ISP's proxy server doesn't support WebSockets. If it goes through, it's either a proxy server issue at your host or there is some issue with your SignalR host configuration. You can use WireShark at either end to have a look at the traffic flowing over the wire. This will help you to see where things bomb out.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried websocket.org and I could connect to the echo websocket. But I still get the 400 Error.

Comment: Wait, so in the log window you see "CONNECTED" then "SENT: Rock it with HTML5 WebSocket" and then you get the 400?

Comment: No, the websocket.org test runs perfectly. My Azure example is not running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254549/signalr-client-connection-error-uwp-javascript-client

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102935/discussion-between-andre-and-cpa).